# How to print a float with 2 decimal places in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, printf, decimal-point

Can I do it with `System.out.print`?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

You can use the [`printf`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method, like so:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", val);
```

In short, the `%.2f` syntax tells Java to return your variable (`val`) with 2 decimal places (`.2`) in decimal representation of a floating-point number (`f`) from the start of the format specifier (`%`).

There are other conversion characters you can use besides `f`:

- `d`: decimal integer
- `o`: octal integer
- `e`: floating-point in scientific notation

Comment: Please be carefull as String.format depend on your current Local configuration, you may not get a dot as a separator. Prefer using `String.format(java.util.Locale.US,"%.2f", val);`

Comment: @gomino Why not `Locale.FRANCE`?

Comment: @erickson in France the decimal separator is a comma and not a dot.

Comment: @gomino Exactly. So why would you put dots in numbers for French users?

Comment: I added this comment as a reminder to warn people who expect to always have a dot as a separator.

Comment: @gomino That makes sense, but I think to "prefer" hard-coding `Locale.US` goes too far. If you need to hard-code a "neutral" locale for case-folding, number rendering, etc., specify `Locale.ROOT`. This would be appropriate for text that will be consumed by another program, rather than rendered for human users. For text presented to a user, honor their locale, whether they specified it explicitly or it's the default.

Comment: how can I store the result `"%.2f",floatNumber` in a `variable`

Answer (score 217):

You can use [`DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). One way to use it:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(df.format(decimalNumber));
```

Another one is to construct it using the `#.##` format.

I find all formatting options less readable than calling the formatting methods, but that's a matter of preference.

Comment: What happened with the `System.out.printf("%.2f", value)` syntax? Is it still around?

Comment: it is. it's still an option - you can undelete your answer ;)

Comment: Looks like it's my option, as I don't know how to use DecimalFormat yet :) Thanks!

Comment: I haven't done extensive Java work in a while, and when I kept seeing `DecimalFormat` answers I immediately had thought I was wrong, but thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: how can i return float value from this value like :float roundofDecimal(float dd){
     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
     df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
     System.out.println(df.format(dd));
     
     return df.format(dd);
    }

Comment: This is a more useful answer to me than stuff around System.out since I'm not dumping my output to the terminal, but rather in to a GUI. Thank you +1 vote from me.

Comment: add `df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);` to force two digits

Answer (score 102):

I would suggest using [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) if you need the value as a `String` in your code.

For example, you can use `String.format()` in the following way:

```
float myFloat = 2.001f;

String formattedString = String.format("%.02f", myFloat);
```

Comment: "%.02f" and "%.2f" is same thing

Answer (score 44):

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, if if enter 10.0000, i am getting 10 only. If i want to display 10.00 then how can i do?

Comment: @Mdhar9e use `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");`

Answer (score 19):

```
float f = 102.236569f; 
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
float twoDigitsF = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(f)); // output is 102.24
```

Comment: Depending on the locale you might get a comma. If you want a dot separator, use this: DecimalFormat("#.##", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))

Answer (score 13):

You may use this quick codes below that changed itself at the end. Add how many zeros as refers to after the point

```
float y1 = 0.123456789;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");  
y1 = Float.valueOf(df.format(y1));
```

> The variable y1 was equals to **0.123456789** before. After the code it turns into **0.12** only.

Comment: It doesn't display 0 before the point. It should be 

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

Comment: For sure! DecimalFormat("0.00") will work, too! Great spot.

Answer (score 11):

```
float floatValue=22.34555f;
System.out.print(String.format("%.2f", floatValue));
```

Output is 22.35.
If you need 3 decimal points change it to "%.3f".

Answer (score 9):

Many people have mentioned `DecimalFormat`.  But you can also use `printf` if you have a recent version of Java:

```
System.out.printf("%1.2f", 3.14159D);
```

[See the docs on the Formatter for more information about the printf format string](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 9):

A simple trick is to generate a shorter version of your variable  by multiplying it with e.g. `100`, rounding it and dividing it by `100.0` again. This way you generate a variable, with **2  decimal places**:

```
double new_variable = Math.round(old_variable*100) / 100.0;
```

This "cheap trick" was always good enough for me, and works in any language (I am not a Java person, just learning it).

Comment: This is wrong, many numbers will be repeating numbers in float representation after you divide by 100. Hence not two decimal places.

Answer (score 8):

To print a float up to 2 decimal places in Java:

```
    float f = (float)11/3;
    System.out.print(String.format("%.2f",f));
```

> OUTPUT: 3.67

*> use **%.3f** for up to three decimal places.*

Answer (score 7):

Look at [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Here is an example from the tutorial:

```
  DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
  String output = myFormatter.format(value);
  System.out.println(value + "  " + pattern + "  " + output);
```

If you choose a pattern like "###.##", you will get two decimal places, and I think that the values are rounded up. You will want to look at the link to get the exact format you want (e.g., whether you want trailing zeros)

Answer (score 5):

Below is code how you can display an output of float data with 2 decimal places in Java:

```
float ratingValue = 52.98929821f; 
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
float twoDigitsFR = Float.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(ratingValue)); // output is 52.98
```

Answer (score 4):

One issue that had me for an hour or more, on `DecimalFormat`- It handles double and float inputs differently. Even change of [RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) did not help. I am no expert but thought it may help someone like me. Ended up using `Math.round` instead. 
See below:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double d = 0.7750;
    System.out.println(" Double 0.7750 -> " +Double.valueOf(df.format(d)));
    float f = 0.7750f;
    System.out.println(" Float 0.7750f -> "+Float.valueOf(df.format(f)));
    // change the RoundingMode
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(" Rounding Up Double 0.7750 -> " +Double.valueOf(df.format(d)));
    System.out.println(" Rounding Up Float 0.7750f -> " +Float.valueOf(df.format(f)));
```

Output:

```
Double 0.7750 -> 0.78
Float 0.7750f -> 0.77

Rounding Up Double 0.7750 -> 0.78
Rounding Up Float 0.7750f -> 0.77
```

Answer (score 3):

OK - str to float.

```
package test;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TestPtz {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String preset0 = "0.09,0.20,0.09,0.07";
    String[] thisto = preset0.split(",");    
    float a = (Float.valueOf(thisto[0])).floatValue();
    System.out.println("[Original]: " + a);   
    a = (float) (a + 0.01);

    // Part 1 - for display / debug
    System.out.printf("[Local]: %.2f \n", a);
    // Part 2 - when value requires to be send as it is
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    System.out.println("[Remote]: " + df.format(a));

  }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
[Original]: 0.09
[Local]: 0.10 
[Remote]: 0.10
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public String getDecimalNumber(String number) {
        Double d=Double.parseDouble(number);
        return String.format("%.5f", d);
}
```

Take care of `NumberFormatException` as well

Answer (score 1):

small simple program for demonstration:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class twovalues {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        float a,b;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Values For Calculation");

        a=sc.nextFloat();
        b=sc.nextFloat();

        float c=a/b;
        System.out.printf("%.2f",c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `String str = System.out.printf("%.2f", val).replace(",", ".");` if you want to ensure that independently of the Locale of the user, you will always get / display a "." as decimal separator. This is a must if you don't want to make your program crash if you later do some kind of conversion like `float f = Float.parseFloat(str);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
private static String getDecimalFormat(double value) {

    String getValue = String.valueOf(value).split("[.]")[1];

      if (getValue.length() == 1) {
          return String.valueOf(value).split("[.]")[0] +
                "."+ getValue.substring(0, 1) + 
                String.format("%0"+1+"d", 0);
       } else {
          return String.valueOf(value).split("[.]")[0]
            +"." + getValue.substring(0, 2);
      }


 }
```

Comment: For more Details:- https://makecodesimpleandeasy.blogspot.com/2019/08/get-two-digit-after-decimal-point-in.html

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this code for formatting decimal precission.

```
    double n = Math.PI;
    DecimalFormat dcf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    float  f = Float.parseFloat(dcf.format(n));   // float value
    double d = Double.parseDouble(dcf.format(n)); // double value
    String number = dcf.format(n);                // String value
```