# How can I round a double number to 1 required decimal digits in Java

Tags: java

I have number like 24 and I need to return like result 24.0. How can I do this think.

I try with this code but is return 24. If is 24.5 is working correct but for 24 is return like integer.

```
double sliderValue = Math.round(number*10)/10;
```

Anybody know how can return 24.0

Comment: The value isn't changing, it is how you display it. When you turn it to a string you should use String.format, or Decimal.format. Consider this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2538803/2067492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing *internal representation* with *presentation*.

The `double` with a value of 24.0... will be *presented* (by default, e.g. when using `System.out.print`) as `24`.

Other methods exist for displaying values with a specified number of digits after the decimal point:

```
double f = 24;
System.out.printf("%.1f\n", f);   // will print 24.0
```

You should also perhaps consider using `BigNumber` instead, which specifically encodes for the number of digits after the decimal point, and treats `24.00` as a different number to `24.0`.

Comment: how can save the result in the variable. I don't want to print it

Comment: @EvgeniVelikov  Your code _already_ produces 24.0 - why do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

Solution 1 :
Returns double

```
double value = 12.3457652133
```

value =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(value));

Solution 2 :
 it would return string

example just for demonstration

```
double Value=i/60000;
String s = (new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(Value));
```

Hope so this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try: (I assume you will only print the result in console and see it)

```
double double1 = Double.valueOf(24);
double double2 = Double.valueOf(24.5);

System.out.println(double1);
System.out.println(double2);
```

This will give you the output:

```
24.0
24.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat

```
double value = 12.3d;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(df.format(value));
```