# Method not correctly calculating and displaying values?

Tags: java

I'd appreciate some help with this.

For example, my code is;

```
class Candy extends DessertItem
{
double weight;
double price;
Candy(String n, double w, double p)
{
super(n);
weight = w;
price = p;
}
public double getCost()
{
double cost = weight*price;
int costinCents = (int)cost*100;
cost = costinCents /100.0;
return cost;
}
public String toString()
{
return name+"\t\t\t\t$" + getCost() + "\n\t" + weight + " lbs @ $" + price;
}
}
```

And the output is:

```
Peanut Butter Fudge             $8.0
    2.25 lbs @ $3.99
```

Why is it displaying $8.0 instead of $8.97?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do you think `(int)cost*100;` does?

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. How would I make it display only 2 decimal points?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try `int costinCents = (int) (cost*100)`

Concrete example:
on cost = 3.5 ==> (int)cost*100 = 300

on cost = 3.5 ==> (int) (cost*100) = 350

Comment: Got it. How would I get it to display $8.97 instead of $8.977500000000001?
I tried using the above link with the .2% and it didn't work because I am using a return, and not a system.out.

Comment: Please refer to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: I saw that, but how would I interpret it into my return statement?
return name+"\t\t\t\t$" + getCost() + "\n\t" + weight + " lbs @ $" + price;

Comment: DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
String output = myFormatter.format(floatValue);

EXAMPLE:
when floatValue = 35.12345f, output is 35.12