# formatting floats to different precisions

Tags: java, format

I have to format a float in Java differently depending on different values.  For instance

```
23 format to 23
24.15 format to 24.15
30.249 format to 30.25
42.7 format to 42.7
```

That is, round up from the 100th place but do not display final 0's to the right (that is 3.4 instead of 3.40 and 7 instead of 7.0) etc.  But again two decimal places max.

I was playing around with String.format but cannot figure out the correct format.  I do need to format the float and write it to a String though.

Anyone have an idea what the format should be, or some other way to format the number (into a string)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an output of float data with 2 decimal places in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`new DecimalFormat("0.##")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> `#` - Digit, zero shows as absent

*Test*

```
NumberFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System.out.println(fmt.format(23f));
System.out.println(fmt.format(24.15f));
System.out.println(fmt.format(30.249f));
System.out.println(fmt.format(42.7f));
System.out.println(fmt.format(53.006f));
```

*Output*

```
23
24.15
30.25
42.7
53.01
```

Answer (score -1):

To start you going to want to add .005 to your float so it rounds properly.

```
floatvariable = floatvariable+.005;
```

Then you need to multiply it by a hundred.

```
floatvariable = floavariable*100;
```

Now you need to cast it to an integer this will remove any extra numbers.

```
int intvariable = (int)floatvariable;
```

Finally, you can divide that number by a hundred and put it back in the float variable.

```
floatvariable = (float)intvariable/100
```

Now you should have a number rounded to the nearest thousandth.

Comment: That won't compile if `floatvariable` is a `float`. It also won't compile, because `floavariable` is misspelled. But, most importantly, if initial value is `23`, that will print `23.0`. OP wants to print `23`.