# how to convert currency format to double in java

Tags: java

I am getting value in currency formate, but i want double format only.

```
String amt = txn.getAmount();
System.out.println("--amt--"+amt);//output:1010
double value = Double.parseDouble(amt);
System.out.println("---value---"+value);//output:1010.0
String ammount=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(value);
System.out.println("--ammount--"+ammount);//output:Rs.1,010.00
```

Here i want `Rs.1,010.00` to `1010.00`

Any mistakes in my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an output of float data with 2 decimal places in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: Why are you having `getAmount` return a string?

Comment: @cricket_007: Not duplicate please carefully observe,

Comment: Yes it is... `System.out.printf("%.2f\n",value);`

Comment: @cricket_007: Not yaar,

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, please [edit] your question to clarify the problem and I'll consider revoking the vote

Comment: [Dont use `double` for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you do **not** want the currency details. In that case, use getNumberInstance() instead of getCurrencyInstance().

Use:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
String ammount= nf.format(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before printing, replace the string "Rs." with "" and also "," with "".

```
String replaceString1=amount.replace("Rs.","");
String replaceString2=amount.replace(",","");
```

This is a way to handle this case.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The usage of "." and "," is language specific. In other languages the usage of "." and "," may be flipped.

Comment: This just for the case (language specific) for which the author put his query.

Comment: The real solution here is to not use the Currency instance at all

Comment: That is why I mentioned in my comment to handle it in a way. It is a perspective to fix it. May be different fr you and different for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this cleaner approach!.

```
      double d = 1010.00;
      Locale uk = new Locale("en", "GB");
      NumberFormat cf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(uk);
      String s = cf.format(d);

      System.out.println(s);

      Number number = null;
      try
      {
         number = cf.parse(s);
      }
      catch (ParseException e)
      {
         System.out.print(e);
      }
      double dClone = number.doubleValue();
```

Comment: That's very verbose for "clean"

Comment: Haha well, I think this is cleaner in terms of other hacky solutions, Do consider fixing this if you have a better say :D