# Java Format Two Decimal Places

Tags: java

I'm getting an error while trying to format a string number:

> Argument type 'String' does not match the type of the format specifier '%.2f'.

The `String` is created by:

```
String cost = Double.parseDouble((Double.parseDouble(".04") * aLONGTYPEnumber * 24));
```

Comment: It did not work. Still gives same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an output of float data with 2 decimal places in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: @PedroHidalgo I think OP has `double` data

Comment: @Kaushal28 ok, it could be a duplicated of this one I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819842/best-way-to-format-a-double-value-to-2-decimal-places This is what he is looking for.

Comment: Your code doesn't show any formatted output commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to print a `String` using a `double` specifier (`%.2f`).

Using:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", d);
```

requires that `d` is a `double` or `Double`, while your `cost` is a `String`.

Try it with:

```
double cost = Double.parseDouble(".04") * aLONGTYPEnumber * 24;
```

and it should work

Comment: Thank You so much it worked. I don't know what i was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You can format your string like:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00"); 
System.out.println(formatter.format((Double.parseDouble(".04") * aLONGTYPEnumber * 24)));
```