# Decimal issue problems using java

Tags: java, spring, types, precision, primitive-types

I'm rounding off some value when I passed these values in my `round()` func, in my round func I used `Math.pow` and `Math.round` to achieve:

`round(x,2);`

`round(xx,2);`

```
float x =4.68;
float xx = 4.00;

after my round off function

public static Float round(Float value, int places) {
        if (value != null) {
            Float scale = (float) Math.pow(10, places);
            return (Float) (Math.round(value * scale) / scale);
        }
        return value;
    }
Output Coming:
x = 4.7
x = 4

expected Output is or REQUIREMENT IS:
x-->4.70
x-->4.00
```

Comment: Do you need it just for printing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display an output of float data with 2 decimal places in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you call function round(x,2) it means you expect as an output a number rounded to 2 decimal places. It's doesn't matter if it is 4.7 or 4.70000. This is still the same number.

I think your issue is about formatting your output for printing. In this case you can use simple code like this:

```
    float x =4.68;
    float xx = 4.00;
    System.out.printf("%.2f", x);
    System.out.printf("%.2f", xx);
```

Comment: i need the value only in float type this System.out.printf("%.2f", x); is converting into String

Comment: @ParminderSingh Within a `float` variable, `4.7` and `4.70` are identical. Why do you need the unnecessary 0?

Comment: @ParminderSingh You have to understand that 4.7 is the same as 4.70, 4.700 etc. If you see value on your screen, it is a String representation of this float. So all you can do is to manipulate with printing method.