# How to increase the floating point precision of a number by using BigDecimals in java?

Tags: java

Let's assume I have a string number such as 1000.0 and I want to create BigDecimal out of it in the following format: 1000.00

edit: And also if the string number already has a floating precision of two decimals, don't touch it.

How can I do this by using BigDecimals?.

Comment: Formatting and precision are different things. In math, `1000.0` and `1000.00` are identical. You might wanna have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2538787) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setScale(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-), something like that:

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("1000.0");
result.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```