# Whole numbers to doubles with one decimal number in java

Tags: java, numbers, rounding

I'm using `DecimalFormat` to round my numbers to exactly with one decimal. However, numbers like `20` don't show up as `20.0` and it just shows `20`.

So my code is like this:

```
int myWholeNumber = 20;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
double toDouble = Double.parseDouble(df.format(myWholeNumber));
System.out.println(toDouble);
```

but the output differs from the wanted one:

**Output**

```
20
```

**Wanted**

```
20.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a float with 2 decimal places in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-print-a-float-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS no it was't

Comment: It's hard to believe you searched "a lot" since simply reading [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) would have answered your question. (Hint: `#` is defined as "Digit, zero shows as ***absent***".)

Comment: @DavidConrad thnx David my mistake is i searched just in **Stackoverflow** not other sites, any way it was really helpful

Comment: It's a good idea to always start with the documentation for the classes you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly have a zero in your format string:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myWholeNumber = 20;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
        double myDoubleNumber = Double.valueOf(myWholeNumber);
        System.out.println(df.format(myDoubleNumber));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
20.0
```

Try it out [here](https://repl.it/repls/LeafyElaborateAngles).