# I can't find out how to work Decimal Format in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to reduce my decimal places down to only 2 but can't seem to find out how.[This is a picture of what I have. Everything is done other than the decimal places. Any help is greatly appreciated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duslq.png)

Comment: Paste your code, no images of it. Also the image did not any any attempt to format the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Hey in one line : `System.out.printf("%.2f", val);`

In detail: Well actually this question is very [similar too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-print-a-float-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)
Here %.2f says that you want to float up to 2 points.

If you want to print till 3 decimal you can say %.3f and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you're asking for but a good way to get a float/double down to two decimal places is to multiply it by 100, round it, then divide by 100.

Comment: I have tried this and it didn't work thank though!

Comment: This *can* work, but floating-point round off makes it unreliable, so you might get lots of repeating 9s or repeating 0s followed by a 1.

Comment: Personally this has always worked for me. I don't know how you guys are doing. If you have decimal D then you can just do Math.round(D*100)/100. If you want to round it another way just use Math.floor or Math.ceil