# Need to round off two points after decimal digit

Tags: android

I'm working on an app and facing an issue. I've tried a number of solutions but nothing solved my problem.
I need to round off two digits after decimal point.

For Example.

9.225 should be rounded off to 9.23

Thank you.

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57945111/8325853)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Kotlin use `"%.2f".format(number)`, for Java use `String.format("%.2f", number)`

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format("%.2f", d)`, this will rounded automatically. `d` is your value.

OR

You can use this

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
Log.d(df.format(d));
```

You can get as a float value as well like below.

```
float value = Float.valueOf(df.format(d)); // Output will be 1.24
```

Comment: I've tried this but what it does it round of to 9.22 as the initial value was 9.225 and I need 9.23

Comment: Which one did you try? I think the second one with covert value into float should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone with a probable over the top solution however this is what i came up with.

It uses regex to split the string value of the number passed and then rounds up/down depending on the leading digit after the decimal place. It will return a Double in the instance but you can change that if you like. It does throw `IllegalArgumentException`, but thats taste dependant.

```
/**
 * @param value the value that is being transformed
 * @param decimalPlace the decimal place you want to return to
 * @return transformed value to the decimal place
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 */
Double roundNumber(@NonNull Double value, @NonNull Integer decimalPlace) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    String valueString = value.toString();

    if(valueString.length()> decimalPlace+1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The string value of %s is not long enough to have %dplaces", valueString, decimalPlace));
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d)('.')(\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(valueString);

    if (matcher.groupCount() != 4) { //0 = entire pattern, so 4 should be the total ?
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The string value of %s does not contain three groups.", valueString));
    }

    String decimal = matcher.group(3);
    int place = decimal.charAt(decimalPlace);
    int afterDecimalPlace = decimal.charAt(decimalPlace + 1);
    String newDecimal = decimal.substring(0, decimalPlace - 1);
    newDecimal += afterDecimalPlace > 5 ? (place + 1) : place;

    return Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1) + "." + newDecimal);
}
```