# How to floor a number to two decimal places?

Tags: java, double, decimal, floor

I'm trying to floor a double data type number to two decimal places but I only get one instead when I enter a number like 150.

For example if I type this :

`double num = 150.52152;`

`Math.floor(num * 100) / 100;`

I get `150.52` and that's okay!

But If I enter `double num = 150` I get `150.0` instead of `150.00`

How do I solve this?

Comment: 150.0 is the same as 150.00, it's just a matter of how the value is presented. You need to use a number formatter if you want a specific output

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in two ways

1. Using `String.format`

```java
String.format("%.2f",floorValue)
```

2. Using `DecimalFormat`

```java
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format(floorValue)
```

I recommend you store `new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00")` into a `final` variable and use it whenever required rather than creating a new `DecimalFormat` object every time formatting is required.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");// Do it once

        double floorValue = 150;
        System.out.println(format.format(floorValue));// Use it wherever you need to

        // Alternatively
        System.out.printf(String.format("%.2f", floorValue));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
150.00
150.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Controlling the number of decimal places is a function of converting the decimal to a `String`. Remember you are viewing a value in base 10 from base 2. Not every such value is representable (for example `System.out.println(0.05+0.1);`). Instead, use `String` formatting. Like,

```
System.out.printf("%.02f%n", 150.0);
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%.02f%n", 0.05 + 0.1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to mention I want to print it in a return statemen like "Purchase value : " + num...  How do I apply the same thing then?

Comment: `return String.format("Purchase value : %.02f", 150.0);`

Comment: @PohovaniVodokotlic see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

To display your awnser at all times with two values displayed after the decimal point you have two output methods. Your first is as follows:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", <YOUR VALUE>);
```

%.2F calls two decimals in a float which is first defined by printf (print float) this cannot be removed as a integer cannot be a decimal.

Yours second option is to use a decimal format. For example:

```
// First define your fromat as decimalFormat
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
// Define number of digits after the decimal point in your case two
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
// Print out our result now formated in what we have just defined
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(<YOUR VALUE>));
```

Although you output a string it can take a float (you may need to put "f" after your value to make sure it is defined).

Hope this is informative.

Comment: What is `round`, how will this display 2 decimals when rounding 150?

Comment: Just use this its easier `System.out.printf("%.2f", val);`

Comment: What is `val`? (I know what it is but please post a complete and useful answer)

Comment: Please see this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-print-a-float-with-2-decimal-places-in-java#:~:text=In%20short%2C%20the%20%25.,the%20format%20specifier%20(%20%25%20). It goes into far more detail than I could in a comment

Comment: It’s not my question and I know exactly how to handle this problem. I am asking of _you_ to edit your answer so it is a correct and meaningful answer.

Comment: Right give me a few minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229618/discussion-between-rabbitminers-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: This answer is now a duplicate so please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this (but I would prefer `String.format` or `System.out.printf`).
Note that trailing zeroes won't be displayed so `100.10230` would show as `100.1`.

Generate some data

```
Random r =  new Random();
double[] dbls = r.doubles(10).map(d->d*1000).toArray();
```

Print the values

```
for (double d : dbls) {
    double df = (int)(d*100+.5)/100.;
    System.out.println(d + " --> " + df);
}
```

Prints something similar to this.

```
738.2358190119878 --> 738.24
902.7752505591593 --> 902.78
467.26349962571953 --> 467.26
503.2049813704648 --> 503.2
20.288046322504805 --> 20.29
409.10379837674714 --> 409.1
559.2821881121522 --> 559.28
288.5513513499909 --> 288.55
124.07583289719682 --> 124.08
535.1799354550361 --> 535.18
```

Comment: The trailing zeroes are what the question is about...