# Cant properly format output

Tags: java

Im having trouble to find a way for formatting this:

```
System.out.println("Product price reported as $" + price + " before tax and $" + result + " after " + this.tax + " % tax"):
```

Im trying like this.

```
String formatDecimals = String.format("%.2f","Product price reported as $" + price + " before tax and $" + result + " after " + this.tax + " % tax"):
```

I want to have two decimals. Any help

Comment: what is the problem you are having? what datatypes are they?

Comment: either way, if you want formatted output, try printf : printf("%. 2f", val)

Comment: `double`,  it says `argument type String does not match the type of the format specifier`

Comment: `"%.2f"` only accepts a numerical value. You supply the whole string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a float with 2 decimal places in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-print-a-float-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  What are the data-types of the variables?  Give an example of what it should look like and how it is actually appearing.

Edit: forgot the obligatory comment that you shouldn't use floating point for money. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to format a string as a float, this will not work. The whole text has to go into the "format" parameter:

```java
String formatDecimals = String.format("Product price reported as $%.2f before tax and $%.2f after %.2f %% tax", price, result, this.tax);
```

Comment: I think you need `%%` to display a single `%`

Comment: assuming that `price`, `result`  and `this.tax` are floating point; needs to escape `%`  like in `%% tax` to have it in the resulting string

Comment: I updated my answer to add the forgotten escape of the `%` sign, @Stefan

Comment: Yeah, now is better, but tax should be without decimals? Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: solved ty, i just changed to .0f